# MissingPropertyException while running test in spock

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I have the following test written in `groovy` (while using `spock` framework):

```
def "#checkPassword check if passwd match"() {
    given:
    def allowedPasswords = ["1", "2"]

    expect:
    myStrategy.checkPassword(myModel, input) == result

    where:
    input | result
    allowedPasswords   | true
}
```

however, when I run it, `allowedPasswords` field seems to be missing. I'm getting the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: allowedPasswords for class:
```

I wonder why, since I declared it in the `given` section. Can you help me with that?

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I expect it to run method checkPassword with allowedPassword as one of the parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look's like you looking for `@Shared`:

```
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

class SpockTest extends Specification {
    @Shared allowedPasswords = ["1", "2"]

    def "#checkPassword check if passwd match"() {
        expect:
        checkPassword(input) == result

        where:
        input << allowedPasswords
        result << allowedPasswords
    }

    static String checkPassword(String input) {
        return input
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your problem is that the `where:` block logically belongs to the text fixture - remember, in case of `@Unroll` "where" variable values will even get compiled into method names! See my sample code below. I.e., `where:` is evaluated before the `given:` block, so you cannot expect it to know a local variable initialised later during the test.

As for the rest of your test code: If there is no re-use of `allowedPasswords`, my recommendation is to just inline it. The answer you already accepted or what I am about to show you as an alternative are only to be used if you re-use the variable in question and do not want to inline it twice so as to make test maintenance easier. Then Dmitry's answer is fine, of course. Without re-use it obfuscates the test code a little bit, though, making it harder to read and understand. I suggest you strive for readability as a good BDD test is a specification of application behaviour, thus the Spock test base class name `Specification` and the Geb base class name `GebSpec`.

Now as for Dmitry's answer, I just want to show that you can use good old `static` as an alternative to `@Shared` and also provide sample code with some re-use making a little more sense and also a little closer to your own test case. I am **not** expecting you to accept this answer instead of his in any way because he answered correctly before me. I am just sharing additional detail here, nothing really new. In his answer I was just missing the explanation of why your code did not work, so I felt compelled to answer, too. :-)

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class AllowedPasswordsTest extends Specification {
  static allowedPasswords = ["1", "2"]

  @Unroll
  def "password check for '#input' should return #result"() {
    expect:
    checkPassword(input) == result

    where:
    input << allowedPasswords + ["3", "oops", "  ", null]
    result = input in allowedPasswords
  }

  static boolean checkPassword(String input) {
    return input?.trim()?.matches("[12]")
  }
}
```